# mongoimport csv file that contains a column with array values

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I am new to MongoDB and am trying to import a csv file containing programme data to MongoDB. One of the fields in the csv file (tags) contains a list of values as such:

[image]

When I import this into mongoDB, the entire field appears as a string:

"tags" : **"**[ethics.philosophy.plato]**"**

Is there any way that I can edit this field (either in the import command or manipulate the data in the database) such that the tag field is an array of values like this:

"tags" : **[**"ethics", "philosophy", "plato"**]**

I have looked online and through the mongoDB mongoimport documentation but have not found the relevant solution. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After CSV is imported, run this command.

```
db.whatevercollection.find().snapshot().forEach(function (el) {
   el.tags = el.tags.split('.');  
 db.whatevercollection.save(el); 
});
```

Edit:
Your CSV Contains Square Brackets.

```
    db.whatevercollection.find().snapshot().forEach(function (el) {
    el.tags=el.tags.substring(1,el.tags.length-1);     
    el.tags = el.tags.split('.');  
         db.whatevercollection.save(el); 
});
```

Comment: This solutions seems to have only worked partially, after running the command I get results like this one:
"tags" : [
  "[ancient_rome",
  "history",
  "italy]"
 ]

. So the first and last item still contain the square bracket from the original string value. I could remove the square brackets from the csv file and then import and run your command, but is there a way to edit your solution so it removes the square brackets with the current collection I have imported?

Comment: Now the output is: TypeError: el.substring is not a function :
@(shell):1:69
DBQuery.prototype.forEach@src/mongo/shell/query.js:501:1
@(shell):1:1

Comment: @sums22 my bad, sorry it should be el.tags.substring. Edited the answer